# How I can bring ListView control in top of other controls in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have a ListView control which is behind other controls. I cant set parent nor use BringInFront function like in winforms to make it front. How I can achieve this in WPF? Bring ListView control in top of other controls.

Comment: Set `ZIndex` Property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the `ZIndex` Property to the maximum.

Read [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2006/06/13/controlling-zorder-using-the-zindex-property.aspx)

OR

Alternatively, just move the `ListView` control to the bottom of the declarations inside the `Grid` (z-order is bottom (highest) to top (lowest)). Perhaps a bit counterintuitive.

Comment: Yes it worked. And also one of the problems were also that my height weren't set properly but this one still was a solution. Thanks.

Comment: For anyone else coming to this thread after all this time, this looks like `<ListView Panel.ZIndex="10">`. 10 is an arbitrary number, if you have assigned other ZIndices to other elements, than the *topmost* element must be the highest number of them all. So imagine if you set `0..2` zindices, the topmost should be `3`. In my case, no other elements have zindices so I just set it to 10 and it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You can do this,

**Goto View->Designer (Shift+f7)**

Right Click your ListView ,

**Order->Bring To Front**

[image]